# generic json parser in java - json.simple

Tags: java, json

I am trying to write a `json` parser string which can parse any json input whether it is nested or not. Any `json` input given to that function can print all key values pair in the `json` passed.

I have tried something like below. I know this is not the correct way but can someone help me out of this. I am using `json.simple`. If it is possible through `json.simple` then please help.

```
public static void parseJson(String json){
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
            JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject)obj.get("results");
            Iterator iterator  = jsonChildObject.keySet().iterator();
            String key = null;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                key = (String)iterator.next();
                System.out.println(((JSONObject)jsonChildObject.get(key)));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

JSON:

```
{   "results" : [      {         "address_components" : [            {               "long_name" : "1600",               "short_name" : "1600",               "types" : [ "street_number" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",               "types" : [ "route" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "Mountain View",               "short_name" : "Mountain View",               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "California",               "short_name" : "CA",               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "United States",               "short_name" : "US",               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]            },            {               "long_name" : "94043",               "short_name" : "94043",               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]            }         ],         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",         "geometry" : {            "location" : {               "lat" : 37.4223895,               "lng" : -122.0843123            },            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",            "viewport" : {               "northeast" : {                  "lat" : 37.4237384802915,                  "lng" : -122.0829633197085               },               "southwest" : {                  "lat" : 37.42104051970851,                  "lng" : -122.0856612802915               }            }         },         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",         "types" : [ "street_address" ]      }   ],   "status" : "OK"}
```

Comment: Can you share the `json` that you are trying to parse?

Comment: I have used google API whose result is in edited post.